Is this an example of Simpsons Paradox in a regression with two independent variables?
I am doing the following regression:
$$\text{home_price} \sim \alpha + \beta_1 \cdot \text{bathrooms} + \beta_1 \cdot \text{sqft_living}$$
I get the following results:
$$\text{home_price}= -17581.822  -1536.354*\text{bathrooms} + 267.132*\text{sqft_living}$$
However, when I start conditioning on bedrooms = 2, 3, 4, 5 (there are only 2 to 5 bedrooms in the dataset), I get the following:
$$\text{home_price} = 50951.877 +  6795.518*\text{bathrooms}+ 270.233*\text{sqft_living} | \text{bedrooms} = 2$$
$$\text{home_price} = -30993.812 +  12964.777*\text{bathrooms}+ 258.223*\text{sqft_living} | \text{bedrooms} = 3$$
$$\text{home_price} = -228122.518  +  19911.07*\text{bathrooms}+ 316.307*\text{sqft_living} | \text{bedrooms} = 4$$
$$\text{home_price} = -490157.558 +  36623.244*\text{bathrooms}+ 379.488*\text{sqft_living} | \text{bedrooms} = 5$$
How do I make sense of the differences in the individual regression coefficients (signs are different) and the regression with all the data?
If this is an example of Simpsons paradox, how do I make sense of it?

What is the model you fit? It seems there are 3 seperate equations here. Did you estimate an interaction

3 separate equations? For the 4 regressions at the bottom, I filter on the number of bedrooms, then estimate

Why not just regress all the data at once? Why filter and then fit a model?

It's a toy example

It is not really Simpson's paradox, but three positively correlated variables: bedrooms, bathrooms and "sqft_living".

But what would explain why the regressions conditioned on bedroom size have different signs than the full regression?

Simpson's paradox is a result of specification error (an omitted variable). It seems pretty clear that omitting the number of bedrooms is also a big mistake in the first model so perhaps it is a version of Simpson's paradox. Question: Are houses with more bedrooms likely to have higher quality builds? (The coefficients in the four separate (conditional) regressions suggest the answer is yes.) P.S. It would be more helpful had you provided significance levels, R-squared etc.

Let me provide that info tomorrow.

Technically, it does seem like an example of Simpson's paradox, but there's nothing particular paradoxical about it. Each equation makes sense on its own. But, since this is a toy example, maybe you're just looking for info on Simpson's paradox. There's a lot out there. Wikipedia is, as it often is, a good place to start. Or, you could ask a more specific question about what really puzzles you.

The opposite signs in the full equation, but not in the individual equations make sense to you? why does it make sense?
